# How to use String.prototype function with JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have code

```
let letters = [
 {"ae": "a"},
 {"ac": "c"}
];

String.prototype.swapLetters = function(){ 
    return this.replace(/ae/g, 'a').replace(/ac/g, 'c');
}

var decLetter= new String(response[i].name).swapLetters();
```

How can I use my prototype function with JSON object values? JSON will be generated dynamically.

Comment: You could use `JSON.stringify`, call your function, then use `JSON.parse` to change it back into an object. It entirely depends on what you want to do, your question is very vague

Comment: I just want to swap letters for string. I have input when I type a response should be a. When I type ae response also should be a. It's like accent folding for autocomplete

Comment: I see no JSON data here. `letters` is an array of objects. JSON is a text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the array and apply the function to each one:

```
String.prototype.swapLetters = function() {
    let result = this;
    letters.forEach(pair => {
      const key = Object.keys(pair)[0];
      const value = pair[key];
      result = result.replace(key, value);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Of course, if you refactor your data, you can make this much simpler:

```
let letters = {
    "ae": "a",
    "ac": "c"
};

String.prototype.swapLetters = function() {
    return Object.keys(letters).reduce((result, replacer) => {
        return result.replace(replacer, letters[replacer]);
    }, this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for!